# Probability of The EM algorithm for GMM

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, machine-learning

I am reading the tutorial below:

[http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/pub/sslicml07.pdf](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ejerryzhu/pub/sslicml07.pdf)

Now I suffer a problem on page38 (38/135)

[image]

I have no idea why they are equal.

Can someone help me to prove of this?

Really Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an application of Bayes rule and total probability:

$$P(Y|X) = P(X, Y) / P(X)$$

But $p(x) = \sum_y p(x, y)$ by total probability.